# How to render a #new view in a popup model. Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I currently have a simple job board created in Ruby on Rails. Jobs can be created, viewed, edited, and deleted. As of right now, users can click on a job title and renders the #show view with details about the listing. From there, a user can click an apply button, which renders a form.

I am to remove the show view, and have the listings with all of their details displayed on the  #index of the job_listing controller. There will be an apply button to each of the listings. This apply button is to popup a model with the application form (#new action in the leads_controller). Once the form is submitted, the popup model is to close and display the job listings again. The link is not to change and the browser is not to refresh.

I know I need to to implement AJAX requests for the data and jQuery to open and close the popup model. What I do not know is how request and display the application form.

Here is my lead_controller(lead meaning application)

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  include LeadsHelper

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

  def create
    @admins = User.where('new_lead_notifications = true')
    @job_listing = JobListing.find(params[:job_listing_id])   
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    @lead.job_listing_id = params[:job_listing_id]

    if @lead.save
      send_leads_to_admins(@admins, @job_listing, @lead)
      send_lead_conformation(@lead, @job_listing)
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      puts @lead.errors.inspect
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def lead_params
    params.require(:lead).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :file)
  end
end
```

Here is my job_listing index where the link to apply should be.

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <% @job_listings.each do |listing| %>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div><%= listing.title %></div>
          <%# <%= link_to "Apply", new_job_listing_lead_path(listing), remote: true, class: "button is-info is-small" %> %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to respond with js in my controller. The js.erb file then ran some jQuery to fill the div.